# Split screen layout with snap to document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to recreate the effect of http://www.wandaprint.com in the way the scroll goes both ways and snaps to keep the content perfectly fit.

I found this

http://jsfiddle.net/licinio/R2m9S/

- with does the vertical navigation.

  ```
  (function ($) {
  var top = 0;

  $(document).ready(function () {
  var contentHeight = $('.right').height(),
      contents = $('.right > .content').length;

  top = (0 - (contentHeight * (contents - 1)));

  $('.right').css('top', top + 'px');
  });

  $(window).resize(function () {
  var contentHeight = $('.right').height(),
      contents = $('.right > .content').length;

  top = (0 - (contentHeight * (contents - 1)));

  $('.right').css('top', (top + $(window).scrollTop()) + 'px');
  });

  $(window).scroll(function () {
  $('.right').css('top', (top + $(window).scrollTop()) + 'px');
  });

  })(jQuery);
  ```

I've tried several plugins - jquery-panelsnap, Scrollsnap, and SnapScroll - but i can´t get it to work.

Has you've realised by now, I'm not exactly an expert in js, but I'm looking very much to learn.

Thank in advance for any help you can provide. :)

Comment: Not really sure what you are looking for but the jsfiddle works with a scroll action.  When you scroll on the jsfiddle result box the effect you describe works.  Are you looking for this to be automatic on page load?..?

Comment: Hi Yuval, what I'm looking for is for the coloured div's to snap, either to the top or to the bottom when the user scrolls, so has to que the divs constantly aligned. I don't know if it's doing that on your end, but on mine it doesn't... I'm on Chrome and Safari on Mavericks.

Meanwhile I've added more code, and I got it working, (more or less) if you check it's just "laggy"

Comment: Seems that it does snap if you play with the height of the result box,  I'll take a look at it this afternoon and see if I can get the JQuery to be dynamic to the height

Comment: Thank you!!!! I'll keep fiddling away too, especially seeing it has issues with keyboard navigation... :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for something similar and I didn't find anything to do it, so I created a plugin with that same functionality some days ago. 
It is called [**multiScroll.js**](http://palvarotrigo.com/multiScroll).

- [Demo site](http://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll)
- [Github repository](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/multiscroll.js)
- [Blog entry](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/multiscroll-js-jquery-plugin-to-create-multi-scrolling-sites-with-two-vertical-layouts/)

It works on touch devices as well as and old browsers such as IE 8.

[image]